# Rails 4 - Simple Form collection by scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, collections, scope, simple-form

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I use simple form for forms.

I have an industry model.

The industry.rb has:

```
scope :alphabetically, -> {  order("sector ASC") }
```

The industry controller has:

```
def index
    #@industries = Industry.all
    @industries = Industry.alphabetically
  end
```

The industry form has:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@industry) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>

                <div class="form-inputs">


                    <%= f.select :sector, options_from_collection_for_select(Industry.alphabetical), :prompt => 'Select' %>  

                    <%= f.input :icon, as: :file, :label => "Add an icon" %>

                </div>

                <div class="form-actions">
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", :class => 'formsubmit' %>
                </div>
        <% end %>
```

I'm trying to get my form input for :sector to use the collection of industries (by calling the scope).

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `alphabetical' for #<Class:0x007fef65635220>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `alphabetically` instead of `alphabetical`.
Also, according to the [options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) documentation, you need to pass at least 3 arguments to the `options_from_collection_for_select` method: `collection`, `value_method` and `text_method`.

Change to the following to make it work:

```
<%= f.select :sector, options_from_collection_for_select(Industry.alphabetically, 'id', 'sector'), :prompt => 'Select' %>
```

Comment: thanks - it gives - wrong number of arguments (1 for 3..4)

Comment: yeah, you need to pass at least 3 arguments to `options_from_collection_for_select `: collection, value_method, text_method. See this: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select and my updated answer. But, the first error was due to a typo.

Comment: What is supposed to go into the name field? When I try as is, I get this error: undefined method `name' for #<Industry:0x007fef4b2b37d8>. Should it be 'sector'?

Comment: yeah, make it sector.